# React Native - Create method in functional component and call this method outside of the component, possible?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, react-functional-component

I have a custom modal component:

```
export default ModalLoader = props=>{
  const {
    loading,
    ...attributes
  } = props;

  function closeModal(){
    console.log('Close Modal Kepanggil coyyy!!!!!!!')
  }

  return(
    <Modal
      transparent={true}
      animationType={'none'}
      visible={loading}
    >
      <View>
        <View>
          <ActivityIndicator
            size={'large'}
            color={colors.darkRed}
          />
          <CustomText style={{fontSize:24}}>Mohon Tunggu...</CustomText>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

i want to used `closeModal()` in `axios instance`, so everytime `axios` get a response, i want to close modal in axios file itself not in all of my component,

let say my axios instance something like this:

```
AxiosHttp.interceptors.response.use((res)=>{
  CustomLog(res.data, 'Interceptor')
  // call closeModal of ModalLoader
  ModalLoader.closeModal()
  return res.data;
},(err)=>{
  CustomLog(err, 'Interceptor Error')
  // call closeModal of ModalLoader
  ModalLoader.closeModal()
  return Promise.reject(err)
})

export default AxiosHttp
```

is it possible to do that?

Comment: The `ModalLoader` here is a component. You cannot call an instance method through it. You need an instance. FYR: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: @Horst actually i need to create a method like [React native image](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#methods), i don't need to call `<Image ref={'someRef'}/>` just to call `getSize()`. I want to call a function that can change `visible` props to `false` in `ModalLoader`, is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component).

Create a context provider with the function you want to use to close/toggle the modal. Then in the ModalLoader (or any component of choice) use the function from that context.

**./ModalContext.jsx**

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';

const ModalContext = createContext({
  closeModal: () => {
    console.log('Close Modal Kepanggil coyyy!!!!!!!');
  },
});

export default ModalContext;
```

With the introduction of react-hooks in **v16.8.0** you can use context in functional components using the [useContext hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

**Axios instance**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { ModalContext } from './ModalContext';

const modalContext = useContext(ModalContext);

AxiosHttp.interceptors.response.use((res)=>{
  CustomLog(res.data, 'Interceptor')
  // call closeModal in context
  modalContext.closeModal()
  return res.data;
},(err)=>{
  CustomLog(err, 'Interceptor Error')
  // call closeModal in context
  modalContext.closeModal()
  return Promise.reject(err)
})

export default AxiosHttp;
```

See working example to play around with here: https://codepen.io/studiospindle/pen/xxxMRow

In that example there is a async function as an example which will close the modal window after three seconds. This is to mimic the Axios example. Also provided an example with a button.

Comment: how can i access props of `ModalLoader` in `ModalContext`?

Comment: Just add that to the context 'createContext'. Think of the context of a _provider_ component. You can define props in that context (in the createContext) and use/manipulate it in whatever 'consumer' component you want. See: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

a simple [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-wave-pc0wj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) on using react context as @Remi suggested

Core part is `ModalContext.js`. It exports the context for other components.
You can edit the state inside the provider if you need more common function/prop.

If you really need a static function to do so. You might need a manager

```
class ModalInstanceManager {
  _defaultInstance = null;
  register(_ref) {
    if (!this._defaultInstance && "_id" in _ref) {
      this._defaultInstance = _ref;
    }
  }
  unregister(_ref) {
    if (!!this._defaultInstance && this._defaultInstance._id === _ref._id) {
      this._defaultInstance = null;
    }
  }
  getDefault() {
    return this._defaultInstance;
  }
}
export default new ModalInstanceManager();
```

In your ModalLoader:

```
componentDidMount() {
      ModalInstanceManager.register(this);

  }
```

then in your static function:

```
ModalLoader.open/close = ()=> {
      ModalInstanceManager.getDefault().open/close();
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer to use `useContext`, `manager` seems like complicated to me. But i want to know how can i change props value in `closeModal()` using `useContext`

Comment: You can take reference from my example link. In ModalContext.js, there is a provider class.